# How can I make a property change from a different xaml Page with the use of MVVM?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I'm newbie in MVVM . I have two xaml pages. the second one cannot be accessed ( Locked ) unless the button from the first page (Introduction page) has been clicked. How can I do that?

The lock page has this code.

```
<Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="LightGray" IsVisible="{Binding LockPage}">
                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Tap_Lock" />
                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <Label Text="Locked"/>
            </Frame>
```

The Introduction page has this code.

```
<StackLayout>
        <Label Text="This is only a simple Introduction Text."/>
        <Label Text=""/>
        <Button Text="Lets Go!!" Command="{Binding UnlockPageCommand}" Clicked="Tap_Next"/>
</StackLayout>
```

This is the the class LockModule.cs

```
 public class LockModule : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public LockModule()
    {
        UnlockPageCommand = new Command(UnlockPage);
    }

    bool lockPage = true;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged(string lockpage)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(lockpage));
    }

    public bool LockPage
    {
        get { return lockPage; }
        set
        {
                lockPage = value;

            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LockPage));
        }
    }

    public Command UnlockPageCommand { get; }

    void UnlockPage()
    {
        if (lockPage == true)
        {
            lockPage = false;
        }
        else
        {
            lockPage = true;
        }
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LockPage));
    }
}
```

and it's not working......

Comment: In your `UnlockPage()` it's setting the private local `bool lockPage` instead of the `LockPage` so your `OnPropertyChanged` is never being called when your command is executed.

Comment: how can I do that??

like this?

    private bool lockPage = true;

or 
    private set { lockPage = value;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of communicating between 2 viewmodels would be using the same instance of same object across viewmodels.

Else have your LockPage property in viewmodels base.

However I would suggest you to have such values stored in app's shared preferences namely app setting.
You can use this plugin to make your life simpler around app settings. Ref Link: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin/blob/master/README.md

Last option would be to consider using messageing centre to communicate between pages and pass values to viewmodels. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center

However the easiest and finest would be, update the value of lock on page one and pass it via navigation parameters to page two.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming both of your pages are bound to the same instance of your LockModule ViewModel, which at least the first misstep I see in your provided code is the `UnlockPage()` method isn't setting the correct variable. It would prevent `OnPropertyChanged` from firing and keep the bindings from updating automatically. Your method for your command should at least be something more like this:

```
void UnlockPage()
{
    if (lockPage == true)
    {
        LockPage = false;
    }
    else
    {
        LockPage = true;
    }
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LockPage));
}
```

Comment: its not working sir. :(

how can I fix it..? Can you help me

Comment: If that didn't fix it you probably need to post more code showing your pages and how you're creating your ViewModel

Comment: can you give me an example